# Когда следует использовать const char* const?

Tags: c, указатели, char, const

Допустим, есть функция:

```
void
mr_push_err_func(u16 _id, u32 _line, const char* const _file, const char* const _comment) {
    mr_errs[mr_errscnt].id      = _id;
    mr_errs[mr_errscnt].line    = _line;
    mr_errs[mr_errscnt].file    = _file;
    mr_errs[mr_errscnt].comment = _comment;

    mr_errscnt++;

    if (mr_errscnt >= MR_MAX_ERRS)
        mr_write_errs();
}
```

Стоит ли в этой функции давать аргументам `_file` и `_comment` тип `const char* const`, чтобы дать гарантию, что ни указатель, ни значение не измениться. Или же это перебор, и достаточно ограничиться `const char*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для себя я использую примерно такой подход - чем строже, тем лучше, если эта строгость действительно выполняется и имеет смысл :)

В данном случае вы действительно не меняете ни данные, на которые указывает указатель, ни сам указатель. Так что писать `const` *можно*.

Но нужно ли? ведь сам указатель в функции является всего лишь копией внешнего указателя, так что если даже вы его и измените в самой функции - ничего особо страшного не должно произойти. Если вы случайно не присвоите ему другое значение, а потом используете уже его.
Конечно, если вы этого опасаетесь - то допишите `const`.

Но тогда, если быть последовательным - то тогда нужно как `const` объявлять и `_id` и `_line`.

Comment: *Но тогда, если быть последовательным - то тогда нужно как const объявлять и _id и _line.*, не понимаю зачем. Ведь через них передаются данные и их нельзя изменить, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: "*И еще - все-таки не стоит начинать имена с подчеркивания;*", а разрешается ли заканчивать подчеркиванием?

Comment: @Eanmos Данные как таковые не передаются и через указатель :) Просто зачем нужен этот второй `const`? Чтобы не вышло типа `_files = какая-то ерунда; superPtr = _files;`. Но с тем же успехом можно сделать и `_line = какая-то еруенда; superData = _line;`. Про подчеркивание сейчас попробую поискать...

Comment: Просто я думал, что `_id` и `_line` нельзя изменить. Теперь понял, как сильно я ошибался)

Comment: Ага, вот из стандарта: 17.6.4.3.2 - *Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
— Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase
letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
— Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
global namespace.* Так что вроде ваш вариант допустим. Ну, я просто в свое время, чтоб не мучиться, сказал себе просто - не начинай с подчеркивания :) Все же уберу свое замечание из ответа.

Comment: @Harry Поддерживаю, не вижу смысла в переменных которые не используются кроме как в области видимости метода, давать имена с подчеркивания.